# Cassandra Clustering Order Desc slower write speed?

Tags: database-design, cassandra

My question is whether setting DESC Clustering order on a table in Cassandra will make the write speed into this table slower than if it were left ASC by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, since the clustering column is determining how data is stored on disk, it's only stored in another order.

That's why you actually cannot modify your keys afterwards since the SSTable files would need to be rewritten.

For deeper explanation take a look at the [compound key documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html).